# Work off files locally and then upload to Adobe Creative Cloud?

Tags: creative-cloud

I have the Adobe Creative Cloud. What's the best practices for the workflow?

- Work and save all projects on your local machine at work and only upload files that you think you may need access to in the Creative Cloud?
- Work and save all projects in the Cloud. Don't save any files locally, just work in the cloud.

Comment: I, personally, would never store files imperative to my business on *anyone else's* server, regardless of who or whether or not they referred to it as a "cloud".

Comment: I'd say this is related to graphic design. It's not a "design" question, but does it have to be? It's totally related to graphic design, just like this question for example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/offline-billing-software-for-freelancers and it's just as opinion based too.

Comment: @Joonas: The issue is the same for every professional creating stuff on a computer; nothing design-specific plays into it, as far as I can see. Hence this **may** be okay to ask on Workplace. However, this does not necessarily make it off-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is save things in your creative cloud folder you are ALREADY working locally, and then it SYNCS to the creative cloud servers (and any other computer you have your cloud account linked to). It's never just on their server. Any backups you have going to your computer should also back up your creative cloud folder.

You should be able to access your creative cloud version even if your internet isn't working. It's only the syncing that won't happen until your connection is back up.

Answer (score 1):

You should always work locally and use the Cloud as a backup or storage only.

The main reason is that it's going to be faster for you since you won't go through a server to reach and modify your files; using the Cloud is a bit like working on your files from an external hardisk. The speed is never as fast usually as the internal system. It's also safer and you risk less losing data if something happens while you're working; Internet connection don't always have a constant flow, and sometimes it can corrupt some files to work through a server because they can get "desynchronized", if I may say it this way.

Answer (score -1):

Always work locally and then back things up to either a shared server or Cloud. Since most companies I've worked at expect everyone to upload to their server I don't usually end up using the Adobe Cloud because that would mean remembering to upload files to three places every time: too much hassle.

Here's something else to think about: if you're an employee and leave the company all of your work will disappear if it's saved to an Adobe Cloud account that gets closed. I've worked at places where that was a huge problem and large amounts of work was lost.