# Software to invoice clients

Tags: software-recommendation, client-relations, freelance

I'm looking for some apps to create your invoices which I want is simple and free (such as up to 10 invoices a month) can be managed and organized the invoices online. 
I have a good one in my language but I don't know any of them in English.

Comment: Have you tried google? There are dozens and dozens of options out there. If in a pinch, just use Google Docs.

Comment: Might find some useful answers here (although I still haven't yet): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/offline-billing-software-for-freelancers

Answer (score 5):

I just send plain text emails for invoices. I've had no need for anything more. Easily organized, searchable, and filtered in the email client.

```
Billed to: [company and address]
_____________________________________________
INVOICE DATE: [the date]
INVOICE NUMBER: [the #]

SERVICES SUMMARY
_____________________________________________

Date      Project               Total

[date]    [ Project title ]     [ amount ]

_____________________________________________

SubTotal  $xxxxx.00
Tax $0.00
Grand Total $xxxx -- Please pay this amount

_____________________________________________

Checks payable to [my company]
can be mailed to the following address:

[My mailing address]

Secure, online payments can be 
made at the following link:
http://paymentlink


TaxID [my tax id]

_____________________________________________

TERMS
_____________________________________________

Payment due upon receipt. 
[Any other terms]
_____________________________________________

[Full contact info for my company]
```

**Form vs function.** When it comes to invoices I don't care a great deal about form. I'm **overly concerned with function**. I want it to be clear, concise, and contain *any* information which may be necessary for payment. I don't really care if my plain text email "looks pretty". I just want to get paid and remove any roadblocks where *that* is concerned.

If a client *specifically* requests a PDF (some do)..,  well.. I have InDesign or Illustrator so generating an invoice formatted however I want is an easy task. Then I just attach the PDF to my email invoice.

I think most of the "generate an invoice for me" apps are designed for non-designers. No app will *ever* generate an invoice to my design preferences. I wouldn't use them any more than I'd use a "design my business card for me" app.

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to look at [FusionInvoice](https://www.fusioninvoice.com/) (I'm not affiliated). Self hosted, simple and totally configurable (especially if you can code).

@Metis this has an entirely designable (html/css) templating system, and best of all simply sends automated invoices to customers on retainer every month in pdf form.

Everyone will have different needs when it comes to invoicing, but for me this was the only one of (many!) I tried that hit the sweet-spot of simplicity and functionality whilst retaining the all important ability for me to design my own pretty invoices.

It even has enough functionality for me to use it as my basic book-keeping system, arking invoices as "paid" and highlighting those overdue.

Comment: I checked that demo, played with it . Even though it is interesting, it seems quite limiting to me. Granted it was just the demo, but Larval templates doesn't mean "fully customizable" - to learn a template system *for your invoices*?  I guess if you're already familiar with Larval. But there are also a few standard things I do that would require several extra steps for each invoice. I'm glad you like it, but to me, it doesn't appear any better (or worse) than *any* of its competing similar products. The only real plus I saw was the non-subscription aspect of it.  To each his (or her) own. :)

Comment: @Metis Well I code you see, so for me it wasn't a mega challenge to template it. (And I don't know Laravel so I guess it wasn't mega-required to do it...it was a while ago..I recall it at least feeling like just plain html and css). I can't think what your extra steps are that this can't replicate, but for sure invoicing is a very personal thing. For my part I invoice the same amounts to the same people month on month, so automating the process was a massive bonus, and a lot of stress of my shoulders.

Comment: As I recall from my search this was one of fairly few self-hosted setups, and that was a real deal clincher for me. I have enough SASS in my life!